# Definition of vaguely tight sequence of random measures

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Is there any concept of tightness in the vague topology? I found the following result form the book "Kallenberg, Olav. Random measures, theory and applications" [image]on vaguely tightness but I'm unable to understand it. I'm curious to know the definition of tightness in the vague topology.